# How to calculate the frequency of an AC voltage given by $ e = 100\cos(\omega t) $

Tags: electricity

The standard equation of instantaneous voltage is :-
$$ e = e_m \sin(\omega t)  $$

In this case :-
$$ e = 100 \cos(\omega t) \\
\implies e = 100 \sin(\omega t + \frac{\pi}{2}) $$

Now, $$ \omega = 2 \pi f \\
\implies f = \frac{\omega}{2 \pi} $$

If the $ \frac{\pi}{2} $ were not present, I would have easily calculated the frequency, but how can I calculate frequency in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a phase shift, and it can be done away with using a suitable redefinition of the origin of the time axis. For calculating the frequency it is irrelevant - you can completely disregard it.

Comment: After ignoring the phase shift, is there a way to calculate the frequency since the value of $ \omega $ is not given in the question ?

Comment: @arandomguy, not from the information you shared with us.